# Not being able to use querySelector in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component and I need to make a few changes on it's html structure depending on what type of button is clicked. I need to remove a couple of divs and create a brand new one depending on which button is clicked. The easiest way I found to do so is by using `queryselector`. I know it is possible cause I've seen people using it before but, for some reason, I couldn't.

Here's the component I've been struggling with:

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { HomeContext } from "../../contexts/contexHome";
import { Api } from "../../services/api";
import { NotificationPopUpComponentStyle } from "../../styles/NotificationPopUpComponent";

export const NotificationPopUpComponent = () => {
  const { userSave }:any = useContext(HomeContext);

  const [foundRequests, setFoundRequests] = useState<any>([]);

  const handleInvitationClick = (data: any) => {
    let token: any = localStorage.getItem('access')
    token = JSON.parse(token)

    if(data.target.classList.value == 'accept') {
      
      const acceptFriend = async () => {
        const accepted = {accepted: true, pendding: false}
        const result = await Api.patch(`/users/friend/${data.target.id}/`, accepted, {headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}})

        const userWantedToFollow = { user_id: Number(data.target.id) };

        const followFriend = await Api.post("/users/follow/", userWantedToFollow, {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      })
      }
      acceptFriend()

      const acceptBtn = document.querySelectorAll(`#${data.target.id}`)
      acceptBtn.forEach(e => {
        e.remove()
      })
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userSave && userSave.pendding_requests && userSave.pendding_requests.length > 0) {
      const getEachUserInfo = async () => {
        const userInfo = userSave.pendding_requests.map(async (e: any) => {
          const result = await Api.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/${e.friend}/`);
          return result;
        });

        const resolvedPromises: any = await Promise.all(userInfo);
        setFoundRequests(resolvedPromises);
        // console.log(resolvedPromises)
      };

      getEachUserInfo();
    }
  }, [userSave]);

  return (
    <NotificationPopUpComponentStyle>
      {foundRequests.length > 0 &&
        foundRequests.map((e: any) => {
            return <div className="userRequestContainer">
                        
                        <img src={e.data.perfil} alt="" />                           
                        
                        <div className="buttonsContainer">
                            <span id={e.data.id} className="accept" onClick={(event) => handleInvitationClick(event)}>Aceitar</span>
                            <span id={e.data.id} className="deny" onClick={(event) => handleInvitationClick(event)}>Recusar</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          
      })}
    </NotificationPopUpComponentStyle>
  );
};
```

If the button I click has the class 'accept', after doing it's requests, it should select both of my spans by their 'id' then delete 'em.

But when I try to so, it display this message:

> ERROR Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '#5' is not
> a valid selector.
> at handleInvitationClick (http://localhost:3000/main.df85e04188aaf6d4ee96.hot-update.js:60:34)
> at onClick (http://localhost:3000/main.df85e04188aaf6d4ee96.hot-update.js:97:31)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:19657:18)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:19701:20)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:19758:35)
> at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:19772:29)
> at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23916:7)
> at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23942:11)
> at processDispatchQueue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23953:9)
> at dispatchEventsForPlugins (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23962:7) ERROR Failed to
> execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '#5' is not a valid
> selector.
> at handleInvitationClick (http://localhost:3000/main.df85e04188aaf6d4ee96.hot-update.js:60:34)
> at onClick (http://localhost:3000/main.df85e04188aaf6d4ee96.hot-update.js:97:31)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:19657:18)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:19701:20)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:19758:35)
> at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:19772:29)
> at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23916:7)
> at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23942:11)
> at processDispatchQueue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23953:9)
> at dispatchEventsForPlugins (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23962:7)

Comment: You could use `document.querySelectorAll(\`[id="${data.target.id}"]\`)`, but you should really fix your design to not have duplicate ids.

Comment: Did you read this part here: `'#5' is not a valid selector`. The string you pass to `document.querySelectorAll` is not a valid CSS selector